# Android 2.3.3 emulator shows "Android_" when started

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am setting up Android 2.3.3 emulator to start doing Android programming. I!

Following are the parameters I set up for the AVD
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXPag.jpg

I have installed Android SDK, ADT plugin in Eclipse Indigo. When I tried to execute a hello world program in my eclipse, the emulator started, and then a black screen with "Android_" was shown. None of the buttons on the emulator worked nor my program ran.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uaFr.jpg

I am new to Android programming and following the book "Beginning Android™ Application Development" to write my Hello World program. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it time.  Open the Logcat (Window -> Show View -> Other -> Logcat) and you'll see the "phone" is starting up.  Usually takes about a minute or so, depends on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try starting the emulator through **AVD Manager** and wait for a few minutes. You can check progress in Devices view of **DDMS** which will give you an idea if the emulator will start or not. If problem persists try starting the emulator with **user data wiped**.